# @ngx-translate/core/src/translate.service.d.ts:1:24 - error TS2305: Module '"../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'

Tags: angular

I have this package.json file, when I try to run using ng serve showing errors like
**@ngx-translate/core/src/translate.service.d.ts:1:24 - error TS2305: Module '"../../../@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'.**

```
{
  "name": "Inventory-UI",
  "version": "7.1.7",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "rtl": "webpack --config webpack-rtl.config.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/localize": "~9.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.0.7",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^7.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.11.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "clipboard": "^2.0.6",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.1",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^9.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^4.0.1",
    "object-path": "^0.11.4",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-messages": "^2.0.4",
    "webpack-rtl-plugin": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your [@ngx-translate/core](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/718) version to minium 8.